# Anko + Content Provider, Doesn't update data on change

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, kotlin, android-contentresolver, anko

I had this weird issue where I used **Anko** and Android's content provider together, I implemented my fragment using `LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` and at the first time data got loaded and my `fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>?, data: Cursor?) {}` got called and data loaded into the **RecyclerView**, But when I tried to update the record everything was OK until the point that the onLoadFinished() was not called!

Answer (score 0):

It took my day to figure out that using the **Anko's Parser** that maps a cursor into an object was the issue:

```
fun <T: Any> Cursor.parseList(parser: RowParser<T>): List<T> = AnkoInternals.useCursor(this) {
val list = ArrayList<T>(count)
moveToFirst()
while (!isAfterLast) {
    list.add(parser.parseRow(readColumnsArray(this)))
    moveToNext()
}
return list
```

}

Long story short: when the user clicks on the **Recyclerview** item, I'd use the cursor from the adapter and moved it to current position then I tried to map the cursor to my model using:

```
val cursor = mAdapter?.cursor
    cursor?.moveToPosition(it)
    Observable.defer {
      val uploadingItem = cursor?.parseList(UploadParser())
      if (uploadingItem == null) {
        Exceptions.propagate(IllegalArgumentException())
      }
      Observable.just(UploadInfoArgs.parseUploading(uploadingItem?.get(it)!!))
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.immediate()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

which the line **cursor?.parseList(UploadParser())** was the issue that my list wouldn't get updated after changes!